# Make a cobra Command flag required

Tags: go

I've created a cobra command and added a flag:

```
cmd.Flags().StringVarP(&primaryIP, "primary-ip", "p", "", "Help text")
```

Is there a way to make it required other than checking the value myself and returning an error?

Comment: I haven't used cobra; does [MarkFlagRequired](https://godoc.org/github.com/spf13/cobra#MarkFlagRequired) not do what you want?

Comment: Hi @JimB I just found out the hard way, that MarkFlagRequired is only a hint and does not enforce a flag ... https://github.com/spf13/cobra/issues/206

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A few months ago this behavior was changed in `cobra`, although the documentation is not very clear on this. Now if you mark a flag as `MarkFlagRequired("primary-ip")` and you don't supply such a flag, running the command will print the help plus

```
required flag(s) "primary-ip"
exit status 1
```

at the end where the missing required flags are stated.

Comment: As a real example, implemented it here https://github.com/EugenMayer/opnsense-cli/blob/master/cmd/openvpn_ccd_create.go#L27 .. https://github.com/EugenMayer/opnsense-cli/blob/master/cmd/unbound_hostentry_show.go#L20 .. and so on

Comment: _ = nginxCmd.MarkFlagRequired("foo") works if you DO NOT use a PreRunE. If you have a PreRunE then you can create a custom response to the problematic flag.

Answer (score 21):

Late but i hope this help you !

First of all, we need to know that `cobra` defines two types of flags.

**[Persistent flags](https://github.com/spf13/cobra#persistent-flags)**: they will be available to the command and every sub-command under it.

**[Local flags](https://github.com/spf13/cobra#local-flags)**: they will available only to the specific command which define them.

---

So `cobra` provides two approaches to make flags required regarding the type of the flag.

On the `init` function of your command, it could be the `root` or any other command or sub-command. Lets create a cli app called `my-cmd` with a sub-command called xD `sub-command`

```golang
// root.go file

var Foo bool

func init() {
    cobra.OnInitialize(initConfig)

    // define required persistent flag
    myCmd.PersistentFlags().BoolVarP(&Foo, "foo", "f", false, "set foo (*)")
    myCmd.MarkPersistentFlagRequired("foo")
}
```

```golang
// subCommand.go file

var Bar string

func init() {
    // just add subCmd as a sub-command of my-cmd
    myCmd.AddCommand(subCmd)

    // define required local flag
    subCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&Bar, "bar", "b", "", "set bar (*)")
    subCmd.MarkFlagRequired("bar")
}
```

When you call your command in the CLI

```sh
# if you don't pass a value for 'foo' flag
> my-cmd
    required flag(s) "foo" not set
    exit status 1

# here you must pass a value for 'foo' because is persistent as well as 'bar' because is local for sub-cmd
> my-cmd sub-cmd
    required flag(s) "foo", "bar" not set
    exit status 1
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you have to check yourself whether the input is correct for your program.

Note that this makes sense, since you may want to check if the input is correct at the same time. In your example you should check if the input exists AND if the input is a valid ip-address.

Answer (score 3):

```
cmd.Flags().StringVarP(&var, "var", "r", "", "")
cmd.MarkFlagRequired("var")
```

Comment: [This old comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105859/make-a-cobra-command-flag-required/66648034#comment70907914_38105859) from [KingCrunch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421223/kingcrunch): stated *I just found out the hard way, that MarkFlagRequired is only a hint and does not enforce a flag ... https://github.com/spf13/cobra/issues/206*.  Looks like this may be fixed, see [enforce required flags #502](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/pull/502), is this now working for you?

Comment: Hey @dbc it is working for me. I tried running my command without the name flag and got

`Error: required flag(s) "name" not set`