# Cobra MarkPersistentFlagRequired not working on Root

Tags: go, go-cobra

Using spf13/Cobra for cli flag parsing.

root command has a field marked required:

```
rootCmd.PersistentFlags().StringVarP(&configFilePath, "config", "c","", "REQUIRED: config file")
    rootCmd.MarkPersistentFlagRequired("config")    
    rootCmd.MarkFlagRequired("config")
```

However, cobra does not raise an error if it's the root command.

If I add a subcommand and add a required field, .MarkFlagRequired raises an error as expected if the argument is not provided on the command line.

Comment: probably you should raise a github issue and ask it overthere, as this is not related to golang

Comment: Making a flag required is discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105859/make-a-cobra-command-flag-required. You can check issue https://github.com/spf13/cobra/issues/206 for explanation and link to example. I would bet that you have not defined a `Run` method for your root command. That could be a reason for the error message for required flags not to be displayed on root. It would help if you can provide a stripped down but complete example.

Comment: Note for someone who meets this issue in the future: If you use PersistentFlags, you need to use `MarkPersistentFlagRequired`, not `MarkFlagRequired`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

func main() {
    var strTmp string
    rootCmd := &cobra.Command{
        Use: "root",
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            fmt.Println(strTmp)
        },
    }
    subCmd := &cobra.Command{
        Use: "sub",
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            fmt.Println(strTmp)
        },
    }
    rootCmd.PersistentFlags().StringVarP((&strTmp), "test", "t", "", "test required")
    rootCmd.MarkPersistentFlagRequired("test")
    rootCmd.AddCommand(subCmd)
    rootCmd.Execute()
}
```

## Output

### sub command

```
 ⇒  go run test.go sub     
Error: required flag(s) "test" not set
Usage:
  root sub [flags]

Flags:
  -h, --help   help for sub

Global Flags:
  -t, --test string   test required
```

### root command

```
⇒  go run test.go     
Error: required flag(s) "test" not set
Usage:
  root [flags]
  root [command]

Available Commands:
  completion  generate the autocompletion script for the specified shell
  help        Help about any command
  sub         

Flags:
  -h, --help          help for root
  -t, --test string   test required

Use "root [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```